# unable to target gmail url through our extension

Tags: javascript, url, gmail

I have been working on an chrome extension, except gmail url all urls have been working in the match patterns ,if we give gmail url  ,not even alert message is getting executed, so i have thought of giving (all urls)  but the problem we are facing is when the code get refreshed by other website we are getting errors except gmail.